# how to alert filename of uploaded file in squarespace form?

Tags: javascript, forms, file-upload, squarespace

I have a form on a page in SquareSpace that allows an image file to be uploaded:-

https://www.colourourstory.com/uploads (try with dummy data if needed).

I need to add the filename of the uploaded image to a hidden field named "SQF_FILENAME" which already exists.

Any tips on how do I do this please as the value is only available after a successful upload?

Thanks

Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest using some jQuery.

For example, you can hook a function to the change event of the `input[type="file"]` and grab its value. Then all you need to do is set the value to your hidden field.

Here is a short code example:

```js
$('.form-block').on('change', 'input[type="file"]', function() {
console.log($(this));

console.log($(this).val());

const fileName = $(this).val().split('C:\\fakepath\\').pop();

$('input[name="SQF_FILENAME"]').val(fileName);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers.